# Applying Tax per customer

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, tax

In Magento 1.9 I want to apply tax per customer wise on cart page. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can apply tax as per your custom tax rules.For that create new tax rules from admin side.

First you create tax zone and rates rule as per your condition.

Goto header menu **Sales >> tax >> manage tax zone and rates** and create rate and zone wise rules.

After that create tax rule from header menu **Sales >> tax >> manage tax rules**.

This may help you.

Comment: like same is it possible for products wise tax, all products have the own tax rate.

Comment: Thanks for above, I agree with above but in my case i want to apply custom tax from customer of admin

Comment: custom tax from customer of admin means? I don't understand your question

Comment: As per client need, i displayed tax identifier into Manage Customer and i need to apply tax rate based on select option from Manage Customer not from sales > tax